# Formula to minimise the output of 2 variable

Tags: analysis

I am working on a problem where I have 2 variables, and I am trying to create a formula that highlights the output if and only if both variables are low.

My variables are time and price change.

If I multiply them, an occurrence with a high time value and low time value can result in a low overall value. This would not meet my needs.

My best idea is:

time^2 + priceChange x Time

Time is always positive and is measured in minutes and seconds and is generally less than 5 minutes. Time is converted into a decimal number by Excel which I believe will always come out as a decimal number.

Price change can be positive or negative and is generally in the range -1%<= PC <=1%

Here is a sample of the data:

Time(min.sec)          Price (%)

02.03; -0.03

04.15; +0.25

03.57; -0.38

02.57 0.80
Can anyone offer me any thoughts?

Comment: Are these variables both positive? Can you give a little sample of your data? Different distributions need different treatments.

Comment: @Badoe I added some new information to the original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, the idea that "both $a$ and $b$ are small" is expressed by an inequality with the maximum function (`=MAX(...)` in Excel). When the quantities are measured on the same scale, you'd just take the maximum of both. When they are on different scales, you introduce some normalizing factors.

So, let's say that $T$ is the number such that time $<T$ is considered low. And $P$ is the numbers such that percentage changes under $P$ are considered low. Then the condition for both being low would be 
$$\max ( t/T , |p|/P)<1$$
which in Excel language is `MAX(t/T,ABS(p)/P)<1`.